# Tests don't run after automatically starting Spring service in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

Goal: Before I run my acceptance tests, automatically start the spring boot application

What I've tried: I added "Run 'Application'" to the before launch but now it just runs the application and doesn't run the tests. Also, the tests run just fine if I remove the "run 'Application'" step and just start the service manually.

How do I accomplish my goal?

[image: Run/Debug Configuration image]
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I'm going about this the wrong way. I need to start the spring application context using the following assertions before my class:

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)

This blog post showed me how to do this. https://www.jayway.com/2014/07/04/integration-testing-a-spring-boot-application/